# Cannot access element's style.height in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to modify an elements height (elementTwo) using another element's height (elementOne) using JS (**No jQuery)**

When I try logging elementOne.style.height, I get an empty string
Using Safari and Chrome inspector's I can see the computed height but cannot access it using JS. It shows up as faded (See screenshots)

[Screenshot of Safari inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZMga.png) | 
[Screenshot of Chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97xnr.png)

```
.elementOne {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
}
```

ElementOne has a min-height set to be 100vh but automatically increases in size based on the device / size of child elements. It does not have a height set. ElementTwo does not have any css by default

I am trying to do this using JS only and **do not want to use jQuery** at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the property `.clientHeight` of the dom-element.
[See the mdn arcticle about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight).

Answer (score 3):

If you want the height *style* for the element, you need to get the *computed* style with [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) (or [`currentStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(v=vs.85).aspx) on old IE):

```
function getStyle(element) {
    if (typeof getComputedStyle !== "undefined") {
        return getComputedStyle(element);
    }
    return element.currentStyle; // Old IE
}

var heightStyle = getStyle(element).height;
```

That will be a string, with units on it (not necessarily the units in the CSS).

If you want the element's *height*, as opposed to its `height` *style*, use [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) or [`element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight). They will be numbers; it's the number of pixels rounded to the nearest whole number.

If you want the most precise information you can get (including a fractional number of pixels if relevant; that can happen), you'd use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Example:

```js
function getStyle(element) {
  if (typeof getComputedStyle !== "undefined") {
    return getComputedStyle(element);
  }
  return element.currentStyle; // Old IE
}
var element = document.querySelector(".foo");
var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log({
    "height style": getStyle(element).height,
    "offsetHeight": element.offsetHeight,
    "clientHeight": element.clientHeight,
    "bounding height": bounding.height
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.3%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```